# How to get distance between a point and a list of highways?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap

I'm new to GIS. I'm trying to determine whether a list of GPS points are within a highway/road (in terms of meters). I have downloaded a OSM file and populated my database using **osm2pgsql**.

I have the following tables:

```
                     List of relations
 Schema |            Name            |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+----------------------------+----------+----------
 public | geography_columns          | view     | map_user
 public | geometry_columns           | view     | map_user
 public | planet_osm_line            | table    | map_user
 public | planet_osm_point           | table    | map_user
 public | planet_osm_polygon         | table    | map_user
 public | planet_osm_roads           | table    | map_user
 public | raster_columns             | view     | map_user
 public | raster_overviews           | view     | map_user
 public | spatial_ref_sys            | table    | map_user
 public | gps_coordinates            | table    | map_user
 public | gps_coordinates_id_seq     | sequence | map_user
```

My coordinates table looks like so:

```
id | longitude  | latitude  |                        geom
```

I populated my table with a few longitude/latitude points, then ran the following function to generate a geometry value:

```
UPDATE vehicle_coordinates SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

I initially tried using the PostGIS function **ST_DWITHIN** like so:

```
SELECT gps_coordinates.id, highway.name
FROM gps_coordinates, planet_osm_line highway
WHERE highway.highway IS NOT NULL
AND ST_DWITHIN(gps_coordinates.geom, highway.way, 5);
```

But no results were returned. I don't think I can just use meters in this function as I'm using latitude/longitude as my base unit. I'm stuck and not sure where to go from here. Can I use **St_Distance** in my WHERE clause? It states that it returns the distance in meters. But I'm not getting any rows returned:

```
SELECT gps_coordinates.id, highway.name
FROM gps_coordinates, planet_osm_line highway
WHERE highway.highway IS NOT NULL
ST_DistanceSphere(vehicle_coordinates.geom, highway.way) <= 5;
```

It could be that my data is bad (I got it from GEOFABRIK, so should be good) or that I'm confusing my units here.

Comment: you need to make sure your tables are in the same SRID -- and do not use 4326 for distance calcualtions. try converting to more local SRID

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. The table from the OSM file is 3857, so I converted my coordinates table to 3857 as well. But I'm getting 0 rows returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, *osm2pgsql* transforms the raw geographic coordinates (EPSG:4326 - WGS84) to EPSG:3857; to populate the `geom` column in your `gps_coordinates` table accordingly (i.e. defined as `GEOMETRY(POINT, 3857)`), run

```
UPDATE gps_coordinates
  SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326), 3857)
;
```

After that, running

```
SELECT a.id,
       b.name
FROM   gps_coordinates AS a
JOIN   planet_osm_line AS b
  ON   ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.way, 5)
WHERE  b.highway IS NOT NULL
;
```

will return all `b.name` of lines per `a.id` that are within 5 *meters* of each `a.id`s point (meaning that, if there are 3 lines near a point, you'll get three rows with the same `a.id` and different `b.name`).

Alternatively, you can transform on-the-fly; with the `geom` column of `gps_coordinates` defined as `GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326)`, and populated with

```
UPDATE gps_coordinates
  SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326)
;
```

running

```
SELECT a.id,
       b.name
FROM   gps_coordinates AS a
JOIN   planet_osm_line AS b
  ON   ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(a.geom, 3857), b.way, 5)
WHERE  b.highway IS NOT NULL
;
```

will yield the same result.

---

**However:**

EPSG:3857 is pretty useless for anything else than serving map (image) tiles, especially doing anything related to measurements, and you should avoid it if possible; in fact, if you don't have a specific reason to store geometries in any (projected) CRS, store them in a geographic coordinate system (i.e. EPSG:4326 - WGS84 Lat/Lon); PostGIS is really good with those (and you can transform on-the-fly), but as you suspected correctly, the unit *degree* that comes with them is equally useless for measurements.

While Projections have their limits outside of their defined regions (distortions), PostGIS has the `GEOGRAPHY` type along the standard `GEOMETRY` type you are currently using that is specifically made to work with spheroidal geographic coordinates, and e.g. measurements are as precise as they can get (at a slight cost in processing time). This is a wonderful alternative to finding a suitable projection for your (possibly multiple) ROI, and you can cast between types on-the-fly (e.g. `way::GEOGRAPHY`) to access their functionality.

I suggest to get a good read on PostgreSQL/PostGIS (spatial) index behaviour and the `GEOGRAPHY` type.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. I don't see a way to import my OSM file with osm2pgsql and have it use the raw geographic coordinates (EPSG:4326). Anyway to do this?

Comment: I tried your query, no luck. I get the error: "ERROR:  column b.geom does not exist". I know I need to use the highway type within planet_osm_line. See the FROM clause in my original query "planet_osm_line highway"

Comment: *osm2pgsql* has the `-l` switch that preserves the Lat/Lon. alternatively, you can alter the column type and transform, or transform on-the-fly like in the example with the other geom column. you need to replace `geom` with the actual name of the geometry column...`geom` is very common, but the OSM tables have `way` I think?

Comment: Yeah you're right, my bad, didn't catch the geom/way in your query. Fixed it and it works, but still no results. I may reload the OSM file using the `-l` switch to see if that helps. Unsure why I'm not getting any results.

Comment: 1) are you sure those points are within 5m of any line? **Note:** `planet_osm_lines` are mainly admin borders and other things, *not roads*; just in case roads is what you want to check against, use `planet_osm_roads` 3) could you post the output from `SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom) FROM gps_coordinates LIMIT 1;` and the same with `way` and the OSM table

Comment: `SRID=3857;POINT(10.5115465 52.276103)` is the result from the `gps_coordinates` table, and `SRID=3857;LINESTRING(1165625.78697112 6844571.38406744,1165632.85575878 6844488.96996564)` from the `OSM (planet_osm_roads)` table. Looks like a mismatch of types?

Comment: On second thought, this makes sense as a road would be considered a line, whereas a GPS point is a point.

Comment: @foadster a mismatch of units and CRS in your `gps_cpoordinates.geom` column; run `UPDATE gps_cpoordinates SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326), 3857);` and try again: both are in EPSG:3857 then, and `5` is in *meter*

Comment: Ok. They both returned 3857 though, I thought the CRS are the same then?

Comment: So that worked, I got a list of results. This is great. I have questions though. 1. I ran `SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('vehicle_coordinates', 'geom', 3857, 'POINT', 2);` on my database, after dropping the `geom` column when I found out that the `way` column is of type 3857. So why did I have to run your query if I did a `UPDATE vehicle_coordinates SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 3857);` after populating my lat/long columns? 2. Is my original query valid? Why are you doing a `JOIN` on `ST_DWITHIN` instead?

Comment: 1) you did the one wrong thing: assign EPSG:3857 to a geometry in EPSG:4326 (set != transform), so a ordinate which is supposed to be 10 *degrees* is then considered to be 10 *meters* away from the equator.

Comment: 2) in this case there is no difference to your syntax, but the `JOIN` syntax is the recommended way to relate tables, and can have significant differences. make sure you know your `JOIN`s!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for ST_Distance states:  For geometry type returns the minimum 2D Cartesian distance between two geometries in projected units (spatial ref units).

Therefore, it is not returning meters like you assumed, it is returning degrees.  Depending on your latitude, one degree is equal to around 111 KM!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

You can use a rough estimate of 5m = 0.00005 degrees.

Use ST_Transform to transform between crs's. ST_SetSRID only defines the crs.

The crs for both layers must match or you will not be able to do any spatial analysis between the two.

If you transform into a projected coordinate system it will improve your distance calculations.

If you use a projected coordinate system with units of meters you can do your distance calcs in meters rather than degrees.

Comment: If I used a value of 5 for example, wouldn't it return everything within a 500 km radius? I'm getting 0 rows returned, and in theory I would get some sort of result.

Comment: Correct.  The distance is just one of your problems.  How are you setting your crs?  You need to use ST_Transform to transform between crs's.  ST_SetSRID only defines the crs.  The crs for both layers must match or you will not be able to do any spatial analysis between the two.  If you transform into a projected coordinate system it will improve your distance calculations and if you use a projection with units of meters you can do your distance calcs in meters rather than degrees.  Does that help?

Comment: Yeah that helps. So after I imported my OSM file, I checked the SRID type by doing a SELECT ST_SRID on the geom column (highway.way). It returned 3857. So I had to drop my custom coordinates table and redefine the geom column as 3857. Even after doing this, I still receive no results. To answer your statements, my CRS for both layers match now correct? So my calculations should work

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you plotted your points and ways on a map?  Do they visually line up how you would expect?  It may be that they don't line up because of an error somewhere in the data?

Comment: Also from your comment I am not sure that you've defined your geom column correctly.  What is the native projection for the coordinates table?  You need to define the geom as the native projection first.  So if it is 4326, define the column as 4326, then when you use that geometry, use it with st_transform like: st_transform(coordinates.geom,3857).  You cannot just arbitrarily assign a projection to the data and expect it to transform itself automagically.

Comment: Hey you should take a course on SQL to unlock the power of postgis.  I like udacity and this course is free:  https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-relational-databases--ud197